# E4 Application.class necessary?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, startup, e4

I'm migrating a Eclipse 3 Application right now, and I wonder if I still need the Application.class.

The reason for my concern is the Quote from Marc Teufel "In the past on RCP 3.x we hooked into the Application*-Classes to popup things like login screens just before the main application came up. With e4 we don't have the Application-Classes anymore, instead there is a standard E4Application-Class which is responsible to create the Workbench Model and startup the GUI" (https://marcteufel.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/231/)

My Eclipse 3 Application.class executed the Workbench and got a RETURN CODE to decide whether to restart or not, and that's barely it...

```
int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());
if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART) {
                return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
            }
            return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
[...]
```

Is this behavior included in the default "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application"-Application Bundle?
I'm using Eclipse 4.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, similar behavior is included in the standard E4Application class. You should not use your own application class.

To do a restart in an e4 application inject `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.IWorkbench` and call the `restart()` method. Note that this is a different `IWorkbench` class from the 3.x `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench` class (which you should not use).